# Tkinter: Treeview XScrollBar not working/Limit widigt width

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

So I am working on my first "large" python project (second GUI), and it is a simple SQLite database manager. As of now, this is what it looks like when it fits correctly... 
[image: Proper Look]

The problem is, if you get enough columns the GUI will extend to the edge of the screen because of treeview and instead of allowing me to use the scroll-bar on treeview to view the rest of the columns, it kinda just cuts them off.

Here is a picture of the problem.
[image: Picture of the problem]

As you can clearly see, the rest of the table is cut off, while the scroll-bar is also disabled.

Here is the code I used to create the treeview table.

```
def table (self, root, c, table, list_columns):
    self.tree = Treeview(root)
    self.tree['show'] = 'headings'
    self.tree["columns"] = list_columns

    self.ysb = Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
    self.xsb = Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
    self.tree.configure(yscroll=self.ysb.set, xscroll=self.xsb.set)

    for column in list_columns:
        self.tree.column(column)
        self.tree.heading(column, text=column.capitalize())

    self.tree.column("#1", width=50)
    self.tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.onClick)

    result = c.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM " + table)
    ROWID = 1
    for r in result:
        self.tree.insert("", END, iid=ROWID)
        pos = 0
        for c in r:
            self.tree.set(ROWID, column=pos, value=str(c))
            pos = pos + 1
        ROWID = ROWID + 1

    self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=8)
    self.ysb.grid(row=1, column=9, sticky='ns')
    self.xsb.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew', columnspan=8)

    self.rowTotal = 3
```

So thank you for any help, and if you need anything else, let me know!

Edit:

So I tried inserting the treeview into its own frame, and setting the width of the frame to a constant and not allowing the frame to  resize, how ever that did not work either...

Comment: I had your same issue. I was able to solve it following the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843814/how-to-use-horizontal-scrolling-in-treeview-here-i-use-tree-view-to-make-a-table                                                                                                                     Essentially, I've added these to each column: anchor='center',width=90,minwidth=100