# How to use horizontal scrolling in treeview,here i use tree view to make a table

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, scrollbar

```
class table(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent,headings=None,data=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent,relief='ridge')
    self.parent=parent
    self.headings=headings
    self.data = data
    self.CreateUI(self.headings)
    self.LoadTable(self.data)


    self.yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.parent,orient=VERTICAL)
    self.yscrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky = (N,S,W,E))
    self.yscrollbar.config(command=self.treeview.yview)
    self.treeview.config(yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)

    self.xscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.parent,orient=HORIZONTAL)
    self.xscrollbar.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky = (N,S,W,E))
    self.treeview.config(xscrollcommand=self.xscrollbar.set)
    self.xscrollbar.config(command=self.treeview.xview)

    self.grid(row=0,column=0)
def CreateUI(self,headings):
    tv = Treeview(self,height=20)
    if(headings==None):
        tv['columns'] = ('starttime', 'endtime', 'status')
    else:
        tv['columns'] = headings[1:]
        tv.heading("#0", text=headings[0], anchor='w')
        tv.column("#0", anchor="w")
        for i in headings[1:]:
            tv.heading(i, text=i)
            tv.column(i, anchor='center')
    tv.grid(sticky = (N,S,W,E))
    self.treeview = tv

def LoadTable(self,data):
    if(data==None):
        for i in range(100):
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="first", values=('sdfa','asdfasd0','asdfasdf'))
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="Second", values=('sdfa','asdfasd0','asdfasdf'))
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="third", values=('sdfa','asdfasd0','asdfasdf'))
    else:
        for line in data:
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=line[0], values=line[1:])
```

From the above code i created a table out of a treeview, my y-axis scroll is working perfect, but i am not able to work on the xscrollbar. kindly help me out thank you. I am attaching one image of the resultant Treeview(table like one).
[screeshot of my tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE9bg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def CreateUI(self,headings):
    tv = Treeview(self,height=20)
    if(headings==None):
        tv['columns'] = ('starttime', 'endtime', 'status')
    else:
        tv['columns'] = headings[1:]
        tv.heading("#0", text=headings[0], anchor='w')
    --> tv.column("#0", anchor="center",width=100,minwidth=100)
        for i in headings[1:]:
            tv.heading(i, text=i)
        --> tv.column(i, anchor='center',width=90,minwidth=100)##
    tv.pack(expand=Y)
    self.treeview = tv
```

some edit in this function helped me through, thank you for those who tried.
I used an extra parameter of the treeview i.e. , the minwidth.
having a difference in width and min width will allow us to go through this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot it looks like your table hast not enough space provided by the root window.
The scrollbar is probably there, but not visible since the table is cut at the rightside , so you need to adapt the properties of the geometry manager you use for the table's root window

Comment: i have more columns which are not seen like a 3 or 4 more columns which arent visible, The issue is the scroll bar show in the image. not the one not shown. the horizontal scrollbar is the one which isnt working . veritical one which exceeds the boundary is working fine.

Comment: can u provide a way to limit the treeview horiziontal size? actually i think that can solve the issue , i could only find the sizing the columns

Answer (score 0):

**you can horizontally scroll treeview**, rezize the colomns(at runtime, drag to the right 'off screen') the xscrollbar gets activated, OR **resize the column (bigger) in you code using an event after creation of scrollbar and treeview, such as push of button(say when treeview gets filled), else '.xview' detects nothing**

```
vsbx = tkinter.Scrollbar(root_search_stock, orient="horizontal")
vsbx.place(x= 40, y = 550, width = 1000)


tree = tkinter.ttk.Treeview(root_search_stock,\
                           columns=column_names,yscrollcommand=vsby.set,xscrollcommand=vsbx.set)
tree.place(x = 50, y = 300)


vsbx.config(command = tree.xview)
```